# Obtain all UserInfo.UniqueId values from Azure AD tenant

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm new to AAD and SSO so please excuse any naivety here.  I feel I must share the situation in order to ask the question.

Using various ASP.Net example projects, I have modified an existing app so that users can link their existing username/password account (stored in the app database) with Azure AD, and use single sign-on instead to access the app.

This was achieved by retrieving the `AuthenticationResult.UserInfo.UniqueId` and `AuthenticationResult.TenantId` values and storing them against the existing `UserId` field, e.g:

[image: Database SSO]

Users do not sign-up for access.  Instead, they are given access by their line manager, so things work differently to the many samples online.  It works well, but managers are complaining that it is a bind to get every user to link up their accounts to enable SSO.

Is it possible therefore, to export every user's `UserInfo.UniqueId` field from an Azure tenant, so that I could import these en-masse and short-cut the process?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a screen where managers can login and associate a user id in your database with UserInfo.UniqueId from Azure AD? Or do you want it completely automated?

Comment: Automated would be preferred, but I'd be happy with anything more than I have now.  Come to think of it, a screen might be needed to perform the cross-referencing of Azure ID's to application ID's...  Unless there's another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of research I have found that it *is* possible to export all unique user Id's using [the Azure Graph API with a select filter](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fgraphdir1.onmicrosoft.com%2Fusers%3FdeltaLink%3D%26%24select%3DUser%2FobjectId%2CDisplayName).

However, it doesn't solve the underlying problem of reliabily matching the values to user Id values in the existing system.  So therefore, without allowing users to 'sign-up', the onboarding/manual-linking process is the only solution.